# Easy way to vertically center align text in the first table column?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, text, center

This is what I get from the code:[image: My code output]

```
\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{3}
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c | c | c ||}
\hline
\textbf{Posizione}&\shortstack{\textbf{Lunga} \\ \textbf{(long/buy)}}&\shortstack{\textbf{Corta} \\ \textbf{(short/sell)}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Call}&\shortstack{$PL_C^{\text{long}}$\\$\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno illimitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to+\infty$\\Perdita limitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$}&\shortstack{$PL_C^{\text{short}}$\\$-\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno limitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$\\Perdita illimitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to +\infty$}\\
\hline
\textbf{Put}&\shortstack{$PL_P^{\text{long}}$\\$\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno illimitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to0$\\Perdita limitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to+\infty$}&\shortstack{$PL_P^{\text{short}}$\\$-\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno limitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to +\infty$\\Perdita illimitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I'd like the first column to be vertical-centered in a easy way. I found similar questions, but the only fews I managed to work make other document tables change and shift to other pages. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replaces `\shortstack` with a nested tabular.  I also added `\bigstrut` to provide more margin for specific lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subtabular}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\bigstrut}{\rule[-1.5\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{1.5\normalbaselineskip}}% \def\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c | c ||}
\hline
\textbf{Posizione}&
\subtabular{\textbf{Lunga} \\ \textbf{(long/buy)}}&
\subtabular{\textbf{Corta} \\ \textbf{(short/sell)}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Call}&
\subtabular{\bigstrut $PL_C^{\text{long}}$\\$\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno illimitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to+\infty$\\Perdita limitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$}&
\subtabular{\bigstrut $PL_C^{\text{short}}$\\$-\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno limitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$\\Perdita illimitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to +\infty$}\\
\hline
\textbf{Put}&
\subtabular{\bigstrut $PL_P^{\text{long}}$\\$\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno illimitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to0$\\Perdita limitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to+\infty$}&
\subtabular{\bigstrut $PL_P^{\text{short}}$\\$-\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno limitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to +\infty$\\Perdita illimitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you! This is simple and works!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with the `makecell` package. Unrelated: I don't see why you set `\arraystretch` to 3.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c | c | c ||}
\hline
\textbf{Posizione}&\shortstack{\textbf{Lunga} \\ \textbf{(long/buy)}}&\shortstack{\textbf{Corta} \\ \textbf{(short/sell)}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Call}&\makecell{$PL_C^{\text{long}}$\\$\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno illimitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to+\infty$\\Perdita limitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$}&\makecell{$PL_C^{\text{short}}$\\$-\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno limitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$\\Perdita illimitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to +\infty$}\\
\hline
\textbf{Put}&\makecell{$PL_P^{\text{long}}$\\$\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno illimitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to0$\\Perdita limitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to+\infty$}&\makecell{$PL_P^{\text{short}}$\\$-\max \{S_{t_K}-Z-P_C,-P_C\}$\\Guadagno limitato per:\\$S_{t_K}\to +\infty$\\Perdita illimitata per:\\\\$S_{t_K}\to 0$}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]